# How do I perform "groupby" and "size" on a dataframe while keeping all the columns, without knowing what are my DF columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have am searching a string within a windows event logs source, without knowing what the string is (it is received as an input from the user), thus I can't predict what would by my Dataframe's columns (every event in windows event logs has different fields, except the field `event_id` and `type`)
I would like to aggregate all fields by `event_id` and `type`, and keep **all** other fields in the output as well.

example:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Describe will generate summary statistics for the Series or DataFrame provided.

```
# Create a key to group by
df['event_id_by_type'] = df['event_id'] + df['type']

# 
df.groupby('event_id_by_type').describe()
```